# How can I configure Travis CI to test correct loading a library repo under PlatformIO?

Tags: travis-ci, platformio

I have a library used by a number of Arduino projects. I use PlatformIO as my build system, so I've created a `library.json` file in the root of the library to identify dependent libraries that should be loaded when I include this library in a project. All good.

Sometimes the dependent libraries get changed - PlatformIO is particularly sensitive to renaming them in the Arduino `library.properties` file. It is a pain when I discover that my library is broken only when I try to build a project that uses it.

I'd like to configure Travis to run periodically (thanks, Travis cron jobs!) and confirm that I can load all dependent libaries.

`pio ci` does not really apply to libraries. `pio test` requires a PlatformIO subscription (highly recommended, but not always an option).

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in `.travis.yml`:

```

## PlatformIO dependency test

```
- language: python
  python: 2.7
  install:
    - pip install -U platformio
  script:
    - mkdir test_platformio_deps
    - cd test_platformio_deps
    - echo "[env:adafruit_feather_m0]" > platformio.ini
    - echo "platform = atmelsam" >> platformio.ini
    - echo "board = adafruit_feather_m0" >> platformio.ini
    - echo "framework = arduino" >> platformio.ini
    - if [ "${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SLUG}" = "" ]; then echo "lib_deps = SPI, https://github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}" ; else echo "lib_deps = SPI, https://github.com/${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SLUG}#${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_BRANCH}" ; fi >> platformio.ini
    - cat platformio.ini
    - mkdir src
    - echo "int main() {}" > src/main.cpp
    - platformio run
  cache:
    directories:
      - "~/.platformio"
```

```

It will create a simple project that depends on your library and then attempt to build it. If all dependencies load, it will succeed.

The tricky line with `TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_SLUG` handles running the test within a PR.